# custom popup on window close

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

i have a jsp file .whenever user closes the screen a pop up with custom message and two custom buttons ( continue and cancel ) should appear .by clicking continue button u should go to another page .and cancel button to stay on the same page .......plz help me out how cud these be achieved ..
Is there a way to change default message I am getting 'Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?' and then 'Press OK to continue, or Cancel to stay on the Current page.' Can I only display 'my message' in between this two messages?

I am using below javascript codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function beforeClose()
{
return "my mssage...";
}
window.onbeforeunload=beforeClose;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this thread for your answer

[How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)